# Numpy Broadcasting Addition

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

If I have an array of  y: 64 x 400 x 20, and another array x: 64 x 400, what's the most efficient way to do x + y, where I broadcast the addition of each element in x into each of the 64x400 pockets in y (so adding each x[i][j] into y[i][j][:]), such that the result is also 64x400x20?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x[..., None] + y
```

Add an extra length-1 dimension to the end of `x` to line the dimensions up for broadcasting.